# Does CloudAMQP have dual support for AMPQ 1.0 and 0.9.1

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, cloudamqp

On CloudAMQP there are logs which are telling that AMQP 1.0 is not supported and that it requires enabling the **rabbitmq_amqp1_0** plugin

> =ERROR EVENT==== Wed, 07 Jun 2023 10:37:59 GMT === 2023-06-07 10:37:59.477653+00:00 [error] <0.8920.2> closing AMQP connection
> <0.8920.2> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:38068 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5671):,
> amqp1_0_plugin_not_enabled

Not sure which service is using AMQP 1.0 as the majority uses 0.9.1 as there is multiple consumers

The question here is would be both protocols **v1.0** and **v0.9.1** be supported if **rabbitmq_amqp1_0** plugin is enabled.